# How to remove index without knowing its name?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, indexing

I want to remove index using MongoDB .NET Driver (v.2.11). The issue is that I don't want to use index name, instead I would like to remove it like in: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-indexes/ **Remove Specific Index** section - providing index schema.
How can it be done?
Now using of:

`MyCollection.Indexes.DropOne("{ _id: 1, somefield: 1 }");`

results in:

`MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command dropIndexes failed: index not found with name [{ _id: 1, somefield: 1 }].'`

Note:
Index exists in collection.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Not sure the exact use case, but you could loop over the indexes, find the one you're after and then drop it by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way currently in the C# Driver to drop an index based on its keys.

You could however search for the index and get the name and then drop the index like the following.

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Person>("people");

// Create a index
var keys = Builders<Person>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.Surname);
await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(new CreateIndexModel<Person>(keys));

var cursor = await collection.Indexes.ListAsync();

// Find the index 
var indexKeys = BsonDocument.Parse("{ Surname: 1 }");
var indexName = (await cursor.ToListAsync())
    .Where(x => x["key"] == indexKeys)
    .Select(x => x["name"])
    .Single();

// Drop index by name
await collection.Indexes.DropOneAsync(indexName.AsString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [dropIndex command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dropIndexes/#dbcmd.dropIndexes) supports giving the index specification. You can invoke it using your driver's helper for executing arbitrary commands, if your driver does not provide a dropIndex helper that takes an index specification.

> MyCollection.Indexes.DropOne("{ _id: 1, somefield: 1 }");

You tried to drop an index with the name of `"{ _id: 1, somefield: 1 }"`. At a minimum you should be using the correct syntax for maps in your programming language.

Comment: I'm aware that this works that C# driver works this way, since I was looking for some solution :)